# Android How to sum total of two different list in same fragment called with retrofit2?

Tags: android, android-fragments, retrofit2

i have two lists called with retrofit 2 in the same fragment both list are of different objects and the response is working ok

Each object has a field (importe (represents money)) that i have to sum (method calculateTotal, that sum the objects of a list), so here is the problem: how can i sum the total of list1 + total of list2??  i need to show in textView the total sum of the two list:

Total.setText(totalAtenciones+totalNotas)

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rendicion, container, false);
...

...
//here is the button that executes the two requests
  imbBuscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getAtenciones();
            getNotas();
            System.out.println("total aten:"+totalAtenciones+"  total Notas::"+totalNotas);
            calcularTotalFinal();

        }
    });
    return rootView;

}

private void getAtenciones() {
    Call<List<Atencion>> call= api.obtenerAtenciones(293,desde.getText().toString());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Atencion>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Atencion>> call, Response<List<Atencion>> response) {
            System.out.println("estamos aquiiii "+response.body());
            List<Atencion> atenciones= response.body();
            layoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            RecyclerView recycler= (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.rvRendicion);
            recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            RvRendicionAdapter rvAdapter= new RvRendicionAdapter(atenciones);
            recycler.setAdapter(rvAdapter);
            calcularTotalAtenciones(atenciones);


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Atencion>> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("FALLOOOOO:  "+t.getMessage());
        }
    });

}
private void getNotas() {
    Call<List<Nota>> notacall= api.obtenerNotas(293,desde.getText().toString());
    notacall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Nota>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Nota>> call, Response<List<Nota>> response) {
            System.out.println("lista de notasssss "+response.body());
            notas= response.body();
            notasAdapter= new ListaAdaptadaNotas(getActivity(),notas);
            listaNotas.setAdapter(notasAdapter);
            calcularTotalNotas(notas);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Nota>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
 private void calcularTotalNotas(List<Nota> notas){
    double total=0.0;
    for (Nota nota: notas
            ) {

        if(nota.getImporte()==null){
            total=total+0.0;
        }
        else{ total= total+nota.getImporte();}
    }
    System.out.println("total notas----"+total);//here it shows the correct sum
    totalNotas=total;
}
 private void calcularTotalAtenciones(List<Atencion> atenciones){
    double total=0.0;
    for (Atencion at: atenciones
            ) {

        if(at.getImporte()==null){
            total=total+0.0;
        }
        else{ total= total+at.getImporte();}
    }
    System.out.println("total atenciones:----"+total);//here it shows the correct sum
    totalNotas=total;
}

//and this is the code that sum both totals
 private void calcularTotalFinal(){

    double total = totalAtenciones+totalNotas;//but the result is 0.0 (i lose the values)
    txtTotal.setText("Total diario = $"+total);
}
```

i use two variables double to save the parcial sum, totalAtenciones and totalNotas, but in the function calcularTotalFinal() both have 0.0 as value. So how can i sum the two total and show the result in textView? thanks in advance.

Comment: if(nota==null||nota.getImporte()==null){
            total=total+0.0;
        }    /* This if block is being always true. Please provide getImporte() method implementation */

Comment: You need to call calcularTotalFinal() method after getting getAtenciones() data and getAtenciones() data. because in current case calcularTotalFinal() metho called before getting datas.

Comment: for computing the sum create a method with two inputs of data objects and call it after each retrofit call.Compute the sum only when both objects are not null.

Comment: @SriMaharshiManchem in my imbBuscar(Button) i call first list of atenciones, second list of notas, and in the end calcularTotalFinal(the sum of both totals)

Comment: yes as the service calls are asynchronous , the calcularTotalFinal method would take inputs as 0 because data is still being downloaded in another thread.

Comment: take two global variables to store the downloaded data and call your calcularTotalFinal(atenciones,notas) in onSuccessfull listner of your both service calls and calculate only when both are not null.

Comment: @SriMaharshiManchem how can i implement onSuccessfull listener? can you show me an example please?? thanks in advance

Comment: sry that is old method but you can check by using response.isSuccessful() for service call success or failure status.

Answer (score 0):

I hope nota.getImporte() is a value which your getting inn your object

Change your logic like this

```
 for (Nota nota: notas) {

    if(nota!=null && nota.getImporte() != null){
       total= total+nota.getImporte();
         }
      }
```

Same to calcularTotalAtenciones also

Answer (score 0):

Because the calls are asynchronous, you are getting the values to be 0. You should compute the values after both the API calls are made.

You can have a look at [RxJava2](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) to handle asynchronous responses elegantly

Comment: can you explain it a bit better with my case, please?

Comment: Like I have mentioned, since the API calls are asynchronous, until the API calls response have come, you wont be able to get the actual value from the API. So to know that you have actually got a response, I am suggesting you use RxJava. You can chain both your API calls and get the appropriate response and then print the response after you have actually received it