# RxJava how two sum response of two list called asynchronous?

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I have two lists of different objects called using Retrofit2. These two list work fine and return all the elements OK. The second part is that both objects have a property "importe" (represents money), so first I need to sum the objects of each list as a subtotal and then sum the subtotal of the two lists to get the Total (totalList1 + totalList2) and show this value in a `TextView`.

My problem is that as I'm using two asynchronous requests I can not sum the subtotals. My code can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293911/android-how-to-sum-total-of-two-different-list-in-same-fragment-called-with-retr).

I tried to use retrofit2 Synchronous request but get an error:

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

So other guys suggested me to use RxJava. Can someone explain with details how to implement in this case? Not with perfect strict syntax just tell me e.g.:

```
//here create rxJava adapter
 ......
// here call the first request for the first List<ObjectA>
  then
//here call the second request for the second List<ObjectB>
.... 
//and here get the subtotal of each list and sum to get total and put in textview...
```

Any suggestion and help is welcome, thanks in advance!

My sdkversion:

minSdkVersion 21

targetSdkVersion 25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First move out of main thread using just operator and subscribing on computation scheduler.

Then use flatMap, in flatMap make two service calls, and then apply flatMap on resulting observables which emit list of objects to get subtotal for each list

Then use zip to get total

```
 Observable.just(1).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()).flatMap( dummy -> {

    Observable<List<ObjectA>> objectAObservable =  retrofitService.firstCall().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    Observable<List<ObjectB>> objectBObservable = retrofitService.secondCall().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

    Observable<Float> subTotalA =objectAObservable.flatMap(lst -> {
        float subTotal = 0;
        for(obj : lst){
            subTotal = subTotal + obj.getMoney();
        }

        return Observable.just(subTotal );});


    Observable<Float> subTotalB = objectBObservable.flatMap(lst -> {
        float subTotal = 0;
        for(obj : lst){
            subTotal = subTotal + obj.getMoney();
        }

        return Observable.just(subTotal );});

    return Observable.zip(subTotalA, subTotalB, new BiFunction<Float, Float, String>() {
            @Override
            public String apply(Float subTotalA, Float subTotalB) throws Exception {
                return String.valueOf(subTotalA + subTotalA);
            }
        });
    }).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(total -> LOGGER.info("total money - to be set on TextView.. "+total));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i sum up the steps:

**Step 1**

Add converter factory in your gradle file

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:x.x.x' // same version 
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:x.x.x' // same version
```

**Step 2**

You must convert the return type of Retrofit to an Observable, so the Retrofit builder should have a call adapter attached.

```
adapterFactory = RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create();
Retrofit.Builder()
               .baseUrl(baseUrl)
               .addCallAdapterFactory(adapterFactory)
               .build();
```

**Step 3**

In the retrofit interface replace:

```
Call<List<T>> getList()
```

Into

```
Single<List<T>> getList()
```

**Step 4**

Then you can use the zip operator, which encapsulates the observables and emit the async result when both are complete.

EDIT: i adjusted types according to your needs

```
    Single<List<Object1>> obsList1 = api.getList1();
    Single<List<Object2>> obsList2 = api.getList2();

    Single.zip(obsList1, obsList2, new BiFunction<List<Object1>, List<Object2>, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(List<Object1> list1, List<Object2> list2) throws Exception {
            double tot1 = 0, tot2 = 0;
            for(Object1 o : list1){
                tot1 += o.getMoney();
            }
            for(Object2 o : list2){
                tot2 += o.getMoney();
            }
            return String.valueOf(tot1 + tot2);
        }
    });
```

Comment: in your example where i execute the call request?? for e.g for list1 i use: Call<List<Atencion>> call= api.obtenerAtenciones(293,desde.getText().toString());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Atencion>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(......

Comment: adjusted according to your use case

Comment: i don't understand what's wrong with the proposed solution, anyway up to you to choose. regards